# Why is Ninject throwing a "did not return a controller" exception when deployed to Azure?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, ninject

I've just deployed an MVC-based web service to Azure. It's been running fine on a dedicated server. It uses Ninject.

When deployed to Azure, I'm getting the following error:

```
The IControllerFactory 'xxx.NinjectControllerFactory' did not return a controller for the name '<DeploymentName>'.
```

where <DeploymentName> is the name of the production deployment (or hosted service - both have the same name) - which seems a little weird.

I'm using the latest version of Ninject from NuGet (2.2.0.0). My understanding was that there was a medium trust issue in 1.x, but not in 2.x.

Can anyone point me in the right direction on this one? As I said, it works fine in the non-Azure deployment - and I've used the same code in numerous MVC 3 web apps with no problems, so it does look like some Azure-specific issue.

Comment: Look for `NinjectSettings` in object browser. Also there's a V3 RC in nuget

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know that some projects run successfully on Azure that use Ninject.MVC3. You should try to use this extension rather than implement you own `NinjectControllerFactory`. Otherwise the problem is most likely in your ControllerFactory and not Ninject.